# Not eliding correctly on QListView in Windows (OS)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I work with both operation systems (windows and linux) and in linux (image 1) ElideRight is working well but in windows (image 2) is not working well. (...) supposed to be "a" instead.

I use the code below for "Eliding".

Also you need to know, this is happening in QListView.

> ui->geometry_list->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideRight);

[image: List in linux side]

[image: List in windows side]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce OPs issue with the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) `testQListViewElide.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QListWidget qLst;
  qLst.resize(200, 200);
  qLst.setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideRight);
  qLst.addItem(QString("A very long item text to make the elide feature visible"));
  qLst.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

My platform is Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10.

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
```

[image: Snapshot of testQListViewElide.exe]

There are in fact no ellipses. However… Please, note the horizontal scrollbar.

So, I added one line to switch the scrollbar off:

```
  qLst.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

Output:

[image: Snapshot of testQListViewElide.exe (w/o hor. scrollbar)]

So, this is working in Windows in general. (I would have been surprised if not.)

---

The claim of OP that an `à` is shown instead of ellipses made me a bit suspicious. This could be a sign for encoding problems. However, as Qt is using Unicode in `QString` such issues are unlikely. (I never experienced such issues while developing with Qt in Windows in daily business.)

Just, out of curiosity, I compared the [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding of `à` (224 = `0xE0`) with the Unicode of ellipses (U+2026), in UTF-8 encoding: `e2 80 a6`, in UTF-16 encoding: `26 20` (LE) or `20 26` (BE).

This doesn't look like a mis-interpreted encoding – at least, no obvious. However, to sort this out, OP had to provide a little bit more info like e.g. an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which makes the issue reproducible.
(Thus, OP could use my MCVE whether it reproduces the issue on OPs platform.)

I suspect that this an encoding problem but happening while the item texts are stored in `QString`s. It's just the list view which exposes the broken item text. Thereby, consider that it's very likely that strings retrieved in Linux are already in UTF-8 encoding. If a `QString` is assigned from a `std::string`, UTF-8 encoding is assumed as well. ([QString::fromStdString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromStdString)).

This is different in Windows where the internal encoding is UTF-16 but these ANSI flavors of system functions (with different meanings of character values depending on current code page) are still available (which are always good for any encoding damage).

Comment: @BatuhanCENGIZ May I ask what your actual issue was? (Just out of curiosity. I was thinking a while WTH might have happened on your side...) ;-)

Comment: I am working rn for a company and this came to me 5-6 days ago as a bug and i have tried so much way and did not find a solution. So decided to write here. That is the whole situation :)